# Type AnyAction is not assignable to type void | Destructor in redux toolkit with react native with typescript

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I'm having an error using redux toolkit with typescript this is my code:

store

```
import { AnyAction, configureStore, ThunkAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { profileSlice } from 'features/user/store/profile-slice';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  profile: profileSlice.reducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

let middlewares = [thunk];
if (__DEV__) {
  const createDebugger = require('redux-flipper').default;
  middlewares = [...middlewares, createDebugger()];
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  middleware: middlewares,
});
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

redux hooks

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { AppDispatch, RootState } from 'store/store';

export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

call in component

```
React.useEffect(() => dispatch(fetchUserProfileThunk()), [dispatch]);
```

and i'm having this error in typescript

```
TS2322: Type  AnyAction  is not assignable to type  void | Destructor 
index.d.ts(881, 27): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
TS2345: Argument of type
AsyncThunkAction<ProfileType, void, {     rejectValue: KnownErrorType;     state?: unknown;     dispatch?: Dispatch<AnyAction> | undefined;     extra?: unknown;     serializedErrorType?: unknown;     pendingMeta?: unknown;     fulfilledMeta?: unknown;     rejectedMeta?: unknown; }>
is not assignable to parameter of type  AnyAction
```

I added typed redux toolkit hooks from documentation but it didn't help.

Comment: what about modify the type `void` in `fetchUserProfileThunk` to `null` or`undefined`? because I think `void` is used as function return type. and what does `profileSlice ` look like?